# Проблема в вычислении линейного выражения на tasm

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Здравстуйте , задача:
Создать * .exe программу, которая реализует вычисления, заданного вариантом выражения и сохраняет результат в памяти.
Входные операнды А, В, С, D, E, F считать беззнаковыми и длиной в байтах, согласно индекса;
К - константа, длина которой определяется значением (согласно варианту). Для ее описания следует использовать директиву EQU.
Само выражение , которое необходимо посчитать на скрине.
только начал изучать тасм , есть такой код:

```
   DOSSEG
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h
.DATA
K dw 7AA0h, 2023h
A dw 016h
B dw 012h
C db 08h
D dw 0002,2000h
E dw 0200h
Temp1 dw 0000h,0000h    ; A*B - 2 байт *на  2 байт, результат - 4 байт
Temp2 dw 0000h,0000h    ; Temp1-С - ,4 байт - 1 байт, результат - 4 байт
Temp4 dw 0000h               ; (D/E) - 4 байт \ на 2 байт, результат - 2 байт
Temp5 dw 0000h,0000h    ; K+Temp4 - 4 байт + 2 байт, результат - 5 байт
X dw  0000h,0000h,0000h ;промежуточный(4)+К(4 байт+  4 байти,результат-8 байт)

.CODE
Start:
 mov ax, @data                                           ;созд. переменных
 mov ds, ax                                                 ;п. в сегмент данных
                                                                  ;A*B                1 операция
 mov ax, A                                                   ;помещение в регистр ах 1 опеперанда
 mov bx, B                                                   ;п. в р. бх  2 оп. 
 mul bx                                                        ;умн. п. р-т в бх
 mov Temp1,ax                                            ;п. знач. ах в нов . перем.
 mov Temp1+2,dx                                        ;п. во 2 ячейку. пер. Temp1 знач. р. дх
 mov ax,0                                                    ;  занул. ах
 mov bx,0                                                    ; занул. бх
                                                                  ;Temp1-C            2 операция
 mov ax, Temp1                                           ; п. знач. в ах
 mov dx, Temp1+2                                       ;п. в дх знач. 2 яч. переменной Temp1
 mov bl,C                                                     ;  переход на  адрес  переменной с 
 sub ax,bx                                                   ;  вычит. без заема  значения c рег. бх от значения с ах 
 sbb dx,cx                                                    ;  вычит. с заемом значения c рег. сх от значения с дх 
 mov Temp2,ax                                            ; п . рез. с ах в 1 яч. темп2  
 mov Temp2+2,dx                                        ; п.  рез с дх во 2 яч. темп2                
 mov ax,0                                                    ;ах занул. регистров
 mov dx,0                                                    ;дх
 mov bx,0                                                    ;бх
                                                                   ;D/E             3 операция
 mov ax,D+2                                                ;п. перем. д которая раздел. на 2 ч.
 mov dx,D                                                    ;  DX:AX 00022000h;
 mov bx,E                                                   ;п. перем. e в бх
 div bx                                               ;выполн. деления, р-т в  АX, остаток в DX
 mov Temp4,ax                                            ;п .промежут. р-т в темп4     
 mov ax,0                                                    ;занул .рег. 
 mov dx,0                                                    ;
 mov bx,0                                                     ;
                                                                   ;Temp2+Temp4      4 операция
 mov ax,Temp2                                             ;
 mov dx,Temp2+2                                         ;
 mov bx,Temp4                                             ;
 mov cx,Temp4+2                                          ;
 add ax,bx                                                     ;
 adc dx,cx                                                     ;
 mov Temp5,ax                                             ;
 mov Temp5+2,dx;
                                                                   ;Temp5+K
 mov ax,Temp5;
 mov bx,K+2;
 mov cx,K;
 add ax,bx;
 adc dx,cx;
 mov X,ax;
 mov X+2,dx;
 mov ah,4Ch;
 int 21h;
end Start;
```

Но я немогу понять :

```
sbb dx,cx
```

Что за вычитание с заемом здесь ? Откуда в сх какое-то значение?

```
mov Temp1+2,dx
```

"+2" это обращение к 2 ячейке массива\части переменной ?

```
mov bl,C
```

для чего здесь переход на адрес переменной с? или это не он?

Спасибо заранне за помощь.

### Сам пример:

[image: Выражение:]

Comment: Лучше спросить у того, кто писал этот код. Очевидно, что в cx никакого вменяемого значения не будет.

Comment: Вообще код какой-то кривой. 1)Откуда в сх какое-то значение? Да, тут значение не присвоено, получим рандом от предыдущей задачи. 2)"+2" это обращение к 2 ячейке массива\части переменной ? Да. 3)для чего здесь переход на адрес переменной с? mov это оператор присваивания, в данном случае, в bl запишется переменная С, никаким переходом тут не пахнет.